# Problem compiling (making) motion_planning_common/planning_environment package

Tags: ros, planning-environment

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,
I was trying to install motion_planning_common and while it is making planning_environment it shows me some errors.
I have the errors pasted in the pastebin and this is the address of the same.

http://pastebin.com/cWzHLLJ0

kindly could someone tell me what is going wrong and whether it is the problem of version changes as i am using electric and the package was written for some other version of ros. If this is not the case, is it dependent on any of my computer configurations ??

~Cheers!
navderm

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11021/problem-compiling-(making)-motion_planning_common/planning_environment-package/) by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2011-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The motion_planning_common stack no longer exists in electric - most of it went into the arm_navigation stack.  motion_planning_common from diamondback will probably not work overlayed on electric, as the architecture has changed substantially.  You can look at the main arm_navigation page for an overview of the changes: http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation .  If for some reason you need the old stacks/packages I suggest you remain on diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) on 2011-08-25**:
Hi, I want to be able to use octomap_mapping stack. For that I was using the motion_planning_common. In case I can use octomap_mapping without it, its fine for me. I want to be able to use the mapping_msgs package in motion_planning_common.

the arm_navigation stack uses the package arm_navigation_m

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to be able to use octomap_mapping stack. For that I was using the motion_planning_common. In case I can use octomap_mapping without it, its fine for me. I want to be able to use the mapping_msgs package in motion_planning_common.

the arm_navigation stack uses the package arm_navigation_msgs and the msgs in mapping_msgs are all contained there except one .. PolygonalMap.msg

So all in all the main goal is installing octomap_mapping but it searches for mapping_msgs. Is there a way around it ??

Thanks a lot.

~Cheers!
navderm

---

Originally posted by [navderm](https://answers.ros.org/users/984/navderm/) with karma: 78 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-08-25**:
You need to use the electric/unstable branch instead of trunk if you're not building in diamondback, or use the releases. This page lists the releases and their SVN sources: http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_mapping/Releases

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-08-25**:
Is there a reason you wouldn't use the octomap_mapping stack from electric?  The deb for that stack are available in ros-electric-octomap-mapping, and the new version has substantial improvements over the older version.